# iOS: execl(3) doesn't work anymore

Tags: c++, ios, c, macos, exec

I'm trying to call [`execl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/execl.3.html) within my iOS application, which is running in the **iPhone Simulator**. But that fails. Xcode shows this error:

> error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file

When going step by step, this error pops up at the moment when I try to step into `execl`.

So, this makes me think that there is a problem with that very specific method. That it actually doesn't exist in the compiled executable? Do I need to link specific libraries? I tried this as well:

```
printf("execl(): %llx", &execl); // get the address of that method
```

Which prints values like: `execl(): 3aeee0e`. However, when debugging it states: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and `Thread 1: 0x0000000`.

Any ideas? I also tried methods like `execve()`, but give the exact same result. In the past, the exact same code work perfect.

<sub>For those who know what I'm talking about: Yes, I really want to use valgrind and not the tools by Apple.</sub>

Comment: I'm actually surprised that `execl` worked at all…

Comment: @DarkDust: Forgot to mention: I'm working in the iPhone Simulator.